# Javascript Floating Point Number Regex Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to match floating point numbers with at most 4 digits before the '.' and at most 4 digits after.

Examples of valid inputs:
1234.5678
123.567
12.34
1.2
1.23
12.3
etc...

Comment: `/\b\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}\b/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many places where you get the answer for it. Here is your required answer,

```
^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,4})?$
```

[Test the answer in this Link](https://regex101.com/)